# Можно ли соединять узами Мнемозину и Юпитера (а не Зевса)? Их дочерей - МУЗ - писать с прописной?

Tags: пунктуация, мифология

> О, капризная Мнемозина. Супруга Юпитера, мать девяти Муз.

Запятая после **О** - авторская.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практически невозможно соединить кого-либо родительскими узами через телемост между древней Грецией (Мнемозина) и древним Римом (Юпитер) - в качестве папы нужен Зевс или Уран.

Comment: А что с музами?

Comment: У этих муз (это разновидность богинь) были имена, но при первом упоминании иногда во вн. числе на них ссылаются с заглавной буквы (чтобы не путалось с распространенным употреблением слова в переносном смысле).

Comment: Можно увидеть примеры, где это слово сначала с заглавной буквы, а потом со строчной? Никогда не встречал.

Comment: Так в википедии, правда, у страницы пока статус "не проверено". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Такой себе орфографический источник, тем более там слово два раза с заглавной и два раза со строчной.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, такая неточность (небрежность?) допустима при поверхностном затрагивании античной культуры, поскольку латинские имена богов воспринимаются как синонимы греческих, никакой смысловой или стилистической разницы в первом приближении я между ними не вижу. Что касается дочерей, то обычно пишут со строчной, однако в данном случае будет уместно написание с заглавной, поскольку, на мой взгляд, тут мы имеем дело с **особым стилистическим употреблением** (фраза из *Справочника по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию* Розенталя). Тем более речь не об абстрактных понятиях, но о совершенно конкретных личностях (ср. «солнце раскалило землю» и «Земля вращается вокруг Солнца» и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

На карте изображена Мнемозина – в древнегреческой мифологии богиня из поколения титанов, **мать девяти муз,** родившихся от её связи с Зевсом.

http://symbolon.su/simbolon/kartyi/mnemozina.html

Прописная буква – авторская орфография. В орфографическом словаре указано, что в обоих значениях муза пишется со строчной буквы.

му́за, -ы (мифол.; источник поэтического вдохновения)

http://orfo.ruslang.ru/search/word